# Rails Server Error from Application.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

just started building out a rails project from scratch after months of re-purposing of older code.  the new project wont allow me to run rails server from the command line.  i'm getting an error reporting the problem is in the application.rb file

```
    rails_projects/platform/config/application.rb:7: undefined method `groups' for       Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

application.rb file looks like this:

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
    require 'rails/all'
    if defined?(Bundler)
     Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
 end
    module Platform
   class Application < Rails::Application
 config.encoding = "utf-8"
config.filter_parameters += [:password]
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rails.groups` method was something that was added in Rails 3.1. By the look of it, you're still using Rails 3.0.9. Change the version number for Rails in your Gemfile to `3.1.1` and run `bundle update rails` to fix this problem.